# Does awk support using a different character than ' in print?

Tags: bash, awk

Does awk support using a different delimiter character than ' in print? e.g. Instead of `awk '{print $1}'`, something like `awk -d # #{print $1}#`

I was actually looking at the C source code and it's a pretty short program; is there an alternative version that allow that?

Comment: You are confused. The `'`s in the script you posted are the **shell** delimiters for a script. It's got nothing to do with awk. If you change your question to explain what you're trying to do instead of how you're trying to do it then we can help you. Make sure to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: @AnthonyC, ...btw, `awk` is a full programming language; it's able to do much, *much* more than just the silly "print the Nth column" purpose it's idiomatic for, and there's nothing specific to `print` about the syntax at hand.

Comment: To be clear, btw, since what you're asking about is shell syntax -- no program called by the shell is able to change how the shell that calls it parses its command line, because by the time the program is started, the command-line parsing is already done.

Comment: BTW, if your goal is to pass data containing literal quotes to `awk`, that's a problem with good solutions available (basically, you want to pass literal data out-of-band from code; something like `awk -v awkVar="$shellVar" '...awk code using awkVar here...'` will work with all possible values for `shellVar`, including ones with single quotes, double quotes, newlines, etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can't: The `'` isn't passed to `awk`; instead, it's understood **by the shell itself**. Thus, when you run `awk '{print $1}'`, what you're actually calling at the OS level is something like:

```
/* this is C syntax, so the double-quotes are C quotes; only their contents are literal */
execvp("awk", { "awk", "{print $1}", NUL });
```

Notably, the single-quotes aren't there at all any more -- they were parsed out by the shell when it understood them as instructions for how it should break the command into an argument list.

Answer (score 1):

To see it in another way, consider if you put your script in a separate file and called

```
awk -f my.awk
```

The contents of `my.awk` would simply be

```
{print $1}
```

not

```
'{print $1}'
```

The single quotes are only used by the shell to ensure that the script is passed literally to `awk`, rather than being subject to any particular shell processing that could change the script before `awk` could read it.